# printing the numbers for a calendar in python

Tags: python, calendar

I am writing a basic calendar program in python.  It takes the year and first weekday of the year as input from the user and then prints the 12 month calendar.  I have everything done except for printing the numbers to the calendar.  For some reason I can not figure out how to print the correct amount of numbers to each line.  I'm not sure if I should use strings or a list or how to go about it at all.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could take a look at the source for [`TextCalendar`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/calendar.html#calendar.TextCalendar)

Comment: How are you wanting to format the calendar output?

Answer (score 2):

```
import calendar
c = calendar.TextCalendar(calendar.MONDAY)
c.prmonth(2013, 11)
```

Then the output:

```
    November 2013
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
             1  2  3
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30
```